# Unable to create multiple instance of tiny slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to add multiple instances of tiny slider. But it only works on the first div.
I wanna add two sliders with the same properties in two different div. First slider works fine but  second slider get broken

```
let tnsslider = tns({
  container: '.my-slider',
  items: 3,
  gutter: 20,
  edgePadding: 20,
  controlsPosition: 'bottom',
  mouseDrag: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayButtonOutput: false,
  controlsContainer: '#custom-control',
  nav: false,
  responsive: {
    0 : {
      items: 1
    },
    768 : {
      items: 2
    },
    1440 : {
      items: 3
    }
  }
});

let tnsslider1 = tns({
  container: '.my-slider',
  items: 3,
  gutter: 20,
  edgePadding: 20,
  controlsPosition: 'bottom',
  mouseDrag: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayButtonOutput: false,
  controlsContainer: '#custom-control',
  nav: false,
  responsive: {
    0 : {
      items: 1
    },
    768 : {
      items: 2
    },
    1440 : {
      items: 3
    }
  }
});
```

This is my HTML structure which i have been using i created two different divs for both the sliders but only first one works as expected.

```
<div class="men-section">
      <h2>Men</h2>
      <div class="tnsslider">
        <ul class="control" id="custom-control">
          <li class="prev">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="next">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="my-slider">
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (2).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (3).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (4).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (5).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (6).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (7).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (8).jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="women-section">
      <h2>Women</h2>
      <div class="tnsslider1">
        <ul class="control" id="custom-control">
          <li class="prev">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="next">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="my-slider">
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (2).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (3).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (4).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (5).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (6).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (7).jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="/assets/img/men-img (8).jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem could be that the container is the same for both `container: '.my-slider'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change your second div class name, and put the same in your `tnsslider1.container`

Edit : try to change your `id` and `controlsContainer`